# Performance considerations with Facebook C# SDK versus Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm starting a new Facebook canvas application so I can pick the technology I'm going to use. I've always been a fan of the .NET platform so I'm strongly considering it for this app. I think the work done in:
facebooksdk.codeplex.com

looks very promising. But my question is the following:

It's my understanding that when using an app framework like this (or PHP for that matter) with Facebook, whenever we have a call into the API to do some action (say post to the stream), the flow would be the following:

-User initiates request which is direceted to ASP.NET server

-ASP.NET server makes Facebook API call

so a total of three machines are involved.

Why wouldn't one use the Javascript SDK instead?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api

"Server-side calls are available via the JavaScript SDK that allow you to build rich applications that can make API calls against the Facebook servers directly from the user's browser. This can improve performance in many scenarios, as compared to making all calls from your server. It can also help reduce, or eliminate the need to proxy the requests thru your own servers, freeing them to do other things."

So as I see it, I'd be taking my ASP.NET server out of the equation, reducing the number of machines involved from three to two. My server is under less load and the user (likely) gets fatter performance.

Am I correct that using the Facebook C# SDK, we have this three machine scenario instead of the two machine scenario of the JS API?

Now I do understand that a web server framework like ASP.NET offers great benefits like great development tools, infrastructure for postbacks, etc, but do I have an incomplete picture here? Would it make sense to use the C# framework but still rely on the javascript sdk for most of the FB api calls? When should one use each?

Best,

-Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should absolutely use the Javascript SDK when you can. You are going to get a lot better performance and your app will be more scalable. However, performance isn't always the only consideration. Some things are just easier on the server. Also, a lot of apps do offline (or delayed processing) of user data that doesn't involve direct interaction.

I don't think that there is a right or wrong place to use each SDK, but they definitely both have their place in a well built Facebook app. My advice would just be to use whichever is easier for each task. As your app grows you are going to learn where the bottlenecks are and where you need to really squeeze that extra bit of performance is needed by either moving stuff to the client (Javascript SDK) or moving stuff to be processed in the background (Facebook C# SDK).

Generally, we use the Javascript SDK for some authentication stuff and for most of the stuff with the user interface. The one exception to the UI stuff is when we are really concerned about handling errors. It is a lot easier to handler errors on the server than with the Javascript SDK. Errors I am talking about are things like errors from facebook or just general facebook downtime.

Like I said, in the beginning just use both and do whatever is easier for each task.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. Your answer was very helpful. I think the best thing for me to do now is just experiment.

I'm currently looking over the source for the facebook C# toolkit as a starting point which will hopefully give me good background before I really roll my sleaves up. Your code is very clean!!

Comment: would it be a bad idea to put a call to fbApp.Get("me") in abasecontroller that overrides OnActionExecuting? I want my app to know, server side, if the user is logged in. (membership is facebook only, only a small db table to store uid and associate some roles). I'm still a tad confused between when to use server side and when to use JS SDK. Thanks!